# How to specify multiple width in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have the next line of code where I specify inline CSS, the problem is the width property.

```
<li style={{ display: "inline-block", listStyle: "none", width: "-webkit-fill-available" }}>
```

I need also to specify Firefox inline width -moz-fit-content but I don't know the syntax, I already tried.

```
<li style={{ display: "inline-block", listStyle: "none", width: "-webkit-fill-available", width: "-moz-fit-content " }}>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If inline CSS isn't a must you can define a class with your 2nd approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class in css with the same property, and use className instead.

Here is an example:

```js
class SampleApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div className={'foo'}>foo</div>);  
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SampleApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.foo {
     width: 50px;
     width: -webkit-fill-available;
     width: -moz-fit-content;
     
     /* not important */
     background-color: #f4f4f4;
     border: 1px dashed #ccc;
     padding: 10px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```